# Julia: How to use/access the null value?

Tags: julia

In R the NA value is available by default however in Julia when I tried

```
function a()::Array{Union{Int64,Null})
  return [1, null, 2]
end
a()
```

it gives the error

> UndefVarError: Null not defined

How do I use null in Julia?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Julia doesn't have a null. See [the language FAQ](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/faq/) and search for "null". If you tell us why you think you need `null` we might be able to help you rework your code into something more Julia-like.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide further details on what an `NA value`/`null` is. In Julia, we have `nothing`(`Void`), `C_NULL`(`Ptr{Void}`), `Nullable`, `NaN64`(`Float64`) etc.

Comment: @RayToal I was just reading the link which talks about a null value https://discourse.julialang.org/t/announcement-an-update-on-dataframes-future-plans/4646

Comment: @Gnimuc I am thinking about Julia's equivalent of R's NA value. My background is in R so I can't fully describe what I wanted in precise Julia language (if I can I probably wouldn't be asking this). Please see comment above for the null I am referring to.

Comment: That is an interesting discussion. I love the part about how software engineers get into huge trouble with nulls (It's called the [billion dollar mistake](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3186) for a reason), but data scientists just want a way to represent missing values. These two conflicting uses cases might be hard to reconcile but it sounds like the Julia people are working on it. Is it right to say you are just into representing missing values?

Comment: @RayToal Yeah I just want a way to represent missing data.

Comment: Then DataFrames' NA is the way to go, per Michael K. Borregaard's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future readers of this question, this has been [resolved in v1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/#missing) via the `missing` object.

```
function a()::Array{Union{Int64, Missing}}
  return [1, missing, 2]
end
```

You can use the `skipmissing` [function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.skipmissing) with array operators if you wish to ignore any `missing` values.

Answer (score 4):

The representation of nullable values is one of the biggest current discussions in julia, and one of the biggest hurdles for the 1.0 version step. The easiest at the moment is probably to use the `NA` defined in DataFrames (which uses DataArrays)

```
function a()::DataArray{Int64}
   return @data [1, NA, 2]
end
```

Read also https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/getting_started/#The-NA-Value-1

Answer (score 0):

`Missing`'s `missing`

```
x = [1, missing, 2]
typeof(x)
```